# OnTouch event, finger on screen but not moving

Tags: android, touch-event

I'd like to perform an action when the user let his finger on a View more than 1 sec.

With `OnTouch`, I can access to `ACTION_UP`,`ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_MOVE`.

The problem is that if the user has his finger on the screen and doesn't move his finger, `ACTION_MOVE` is not triggered and thus I can't perform my action.

I precise that I'd like to perform my action after 1sec but while the user still have its finger on screen.

In fact I'd need to sense that the user has his finger on the screen even if he's not moving it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just listen to `ACTION_DOWN` and start a Timer, and do whatever you want to do after 1000ms?

Comment: Ok, so I start the timer on `ACTION_DOWN` and but then where should I put my `if (timer>1000) {Dotask;}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Make Use of the TimerTask class and schedule a Task which will run after a specific time.

[Here is an Example.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

In case the user has lifted his finger before 1000 ms then just cancel the task scheduled upon ACTION_UP event.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a longclickListener :)

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
wv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like the best option, unless he wants to make sure it's one second, no more, no less

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need indeed to deal with precise time. So I think I'll go with a TimerTask as Sudhaker suggested.